# Is there a way to return more response besides the "eventInstanceId" in the API after firing a trigger to a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobileconnect, mobilesdk, marketingcloudapi

Is there a way to return more response besides the "eventInstanceId" in the API after firing a trigger to a journey, Like I also want to get additional information in the In-app OR Mobile Push message like Title, Description and EventDate?

Thanks!